# MySQL / MariaDB: how to find gaps in timebased data?

Tags: mysql, syntax

A logger system saves every 5 seconds a row of data (seconds==0,5,10,15,...,55; a time like `23:00:07` is not possible).

Sometimes the logger doesn't save because of a communication error, and rows are simply missing from the table.

I need to detect these gaps: I want to read the last line before the gap and the first line after the gap.

These are the demo data:

```
create table #time (
    DateTime datetime not null,
    Value int not null
);

insert into #time (DateTime, Value)
    values
        ('2018-08-23 00:00:00', 123),
        ('2018-08-23 00:00:05', 152),
        ('2018-08-23 00:00:10',  37),
        ('2018-08-23 00:00:15', 141),
        ('2018-08-23 00:00:20',  41),
        ('2018-08-23 00:00:25',  35),
        ('2018-08-23 00:00:30', 143),
        ('2018-08-23 00:00:35',  67),
        ('2018-08-23 00:00:40', 111),
                                        /* gap of one minute here */
        ('2018-08-23 00:01:45', 123),
        ('2018-08-23 00:01:50', 145),
        ('2018-08-23 00:01:55', 141),
        ('2018-08-23 00:02:00',  87),
                                        /* gap of 10 seconds here */
        ('2018-08-23 00:02:15', 190),
        ('2018-08-23 00:02:20', 122),
        ('2018-08-23 00:02:25', 123);

select * from #time;
```

They are also at [RexTester](http://rextester.com/AMEC43472)

I would like to read back:

```
    GapStart              GapEnd                Size
0   2018-08-23 00:00:40   2018-08-23 00:01:45   0000-00-00 00:01:45
1   2018-08-23 00:02:00   2018-08-23 00:02:15   0000-00-00 00:00:15
```

Of course gaps of 5 seconds shouldn't be listed

What I found is referred to start/end DateTimes in the same row ([Find gaps in timesheet data between certain hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45444166/find-gaps-in-timesheet-data-between-certain-hours)), or is too complicated *for me* to be adapted to my case ([find gaps in sequential dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35200652/find-gaps-in-sequential-dates)).

I'm using MariaDB 10.0.28 (it is not possible to upgrade it): it means `LAG()` is not available.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You gave a SQL Server demo, so I ported your code over to a MySQL demo, and then updated the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach might be to first subquery and pair each record with the record having the nearest greater timestamp.  Then, query that, and return all records having a gap of a sufficient size.

```
SELECT
    DateTime AS GapStart,
    NextDateTime AS GapEnd,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, DateTime, NextDateTime) AS SizeInSecond
FROM
(
    SELECT DateTime, Value,
        (SELECT MIN(DateTime) FROM #time t2
         WHERE t2.DateTime > t1.DateTime) AS NextDateTime
    FROM #time t1
) t
WHERE
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, DateTime, NextDateTime) > 5;   -- or whatever threshhold you want
```

[image]

### Demo

**ADD ON to original answer**

If `DateTime` is always growing, speed improvement can be obtained by changing the internal SELECT:

```
SELECT
    DateTime AS GapStart,
    NextDateTime AS GapEnd,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, DateTime, NextDateTime) AS SizeInSecond
FROM
(
    SELECT DateTime, Value,
        (SELECT DateTime FROM #time t2
         WHERE t2.DateTime > t1.DateTime LIMIT 1) AS NextDateTime
    FROM #time t1
) t
WHERE
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, DateTime, NextDateTime) > 5;
```